# Change height of large Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a **large bootstrap** modal that I am using from the documentation website:

- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes

After adjusting it to my needs, this is what I have:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="editPackageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editPackages" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Package</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    <label class="control-label">Package Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="package-name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <!-- Other fields here-->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="savePackageChangesBtn" >Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is that I want the Modal's height to be bigger than it is now because when the user starts typing content, the modal "grows" and that is quite ugly. Instead, I prefer to have a big modal, with a fixed size and use scrolling if needed inside the modal.

To achieve this I added `<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="height:80%;">`, but it did nothing.

If however, I use `<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="height:600px;">` I end up with a retarded modal:

[image]

So now I am out of options and out of ideas. How can I achieve the following objectives?

1. Have a Modal that has X% of the screen's height (like 80%)
2. Have a Modal with that fixed size, and make the content scrollabe if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#editPackageModal .modal-body{
  max-height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Chanhe max-height to your needs

Comment: It only fixes a part of the problem, but it is better than anything. Also, the reading on vh was interesting. Thx for showing it !

Answer (score 1):

Try giving max-height and make the dive scroll y

```
max-height:80%;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

I hope it works.